# Multiple Plot Types on Single Subplot Pyplot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm currently trying to create a figure with four subplots. On each subplot I'd like to plot a dataset with error bars. However, for one of the data sets, I'd like to also plot a polynomial fit to that data on the same subplot. My code is something like the following:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# define four sets of data here: x1, y1, yerr1, x2, y2, yerr2, etc...

fit1 = np.poly1d(np.polyfit(x1,y1,1))
xrange = np.linspace(min(x1), max(x1), num = 1000)

f, axarr = plt.subplots(2,2)
axarr[0,0].plot(xrange, fit1(xrange))
axarr[0,0].errorbar(x1, y1, yerr = yerr1, fmt = 'r.')
# and for the rest just the errorbar portion

plt.show()
```

However, what I wind up with is the following:

[image: Bad graph]

So I have the fit for data set 1 on the first subplot, nothing on the second subplot, data sets 1 and 2 on the third subplot and data sets 1 and 2 on the fourth subplot. Is there any way for me to get what I want (i.e. data set 1 with fit on subplot 1, data set 2 on subplot 2, etc.)?

Thanks!

Comment: Please, try to be more specific with you question. It's not clear what the problem is here.

Comment: You should include the code you've tried, sample input, the output you're getting and how that differs from what you expect to get.

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally hit enter early!

Comment: you're going to have to show the rest of your code (all the `axarr[a,b].errorbar` commands, at least)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not quite clear from your code what you are doing. But you can call `plt.subplot(2,2,1)` then do all your plot commands for the top left plot and then call `plt.subplot(2,2,2)` followed by your plot commands to the next subplot, etc.

Matplotlib stores your last subplot (or axes object) and all plot commands are plotted in to the last subplot.

```
plt.subplot(2,2,1)
plt.plot(data_x,data_y,'o')
plt.plot(data_x,fit_y,'-')

plt.subplot(2,2,2)
plt.plot(...
```